# How to optimize calling Trix library in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker, trix

I'm new to **webpacker**. After include Trix on my RoR project based in [documentation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html#installation) , my views are calling it when they are uploaded and seems that Trix is too heavy despite of using `javascript_packs_with_chunks_tag` and just having `application.js` in my javascript/pack folder. is there a way to optimize Trix or a better way to manage it. I just need it for a view, and I'd like to be able to call it just for that view if this is the only option.